# how to get current date within an Azure function?

Tags: python, azure, date, environment-variables, updates

I have a daily running Azure Function with some Python code in it.
In this Python code, I need to get current date, so every day, current date has to be updated.
I noticed that current date is only updated when I deploy the function app, which is quite problematic.

Here is my code :

```
from date time import date, timedelta, datetime 
today = date.today()
```

Last time I deployed it was on February 2nd 2023.
We are on February 8th 2023, and output files are behaving as if it is still February 2nd 2023.

Locally, everything works perfectly.
Do you have any idea why this happening?

Comment: The code you showed will work to get today's date, so the problem is somewhere else. Seems like the py script just isn't running if date is not updated. Please add some more info

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the function app, the current date is updated because the deployment causes a new execution of the function, which updates the date. However, if the function is not called on a daily basis, the date is not updated.

Possibly, You can schedule a function to run at a specific time every day using an `Azure Timer Trigger`. You can set the timer trigger to run the function once a day and update the current date in your code.

```py
import  datetime
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func
def  main(newtimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
if  newtimer.past_due:
logging.info('Past due.')
logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
currentday = datetime.date.today()
logging.info('current day is %s', today)
```

***Triggered successfully in local environment:***

[image]

***Deployment successful from local to Azure Function App:***

[image]

***Deployed to Azure function App and ran successfully:***

[image]